# Angular-cli build to production bootstrap error

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular5

I'm trying to build an Angular 5 project for deployment to IIS.

When I run the following command:

```
ng build --prod
```

I get the following error:

> Error in ./node-modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.
>
> Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major.

I read about this error and saw a suggested solution is to upgrade your Angular CLI to 1.7.0 or newer. My CLI version is 1.7.3 and Bootstrap version is 4.0.0.

How do I fix this error so that I can build my solution?

Comment: Try to delete caret ‘^’ of the bootstrap entry in the package.json

Comment: Have you attempted updating the Angular CLI globally? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: I tried to delete the caret - still not working.  @ForestG

Comment: My global cli is up to date (1.7.3) and I run the build from global cli. @ShellNinja

Comment: How do you include bootstrap's css?

Comment: Added it to the dependencies and the npm install. Also added bootstrap: [AppComponent] in appModule. It works fine in my app @David when I run it with npm start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That issue is mentionned here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020
but should normally not occur in angular cli v1.7.0

Try the other workaround:

Remove "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" from the styles section in `.angular-cli.json`.

Try including bootstrap's css directly in your global `styles.css` file

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

or `styles.scss` file

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of bootstrap are you using?? I've the same issue with 4.1.2 and I changed it to 4.1.1, finally it's working!